# Grepping rails log in logstash, greediness captures all requests

Tags: regex, logstash

I have such a pattern in logstash multiline filter:

```
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "^Started.*ActiveRecord: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1})ms\).+?"
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
    stream_identity => "%{host}.%{path}.%{type}"
  }
}
```

But the problem here is that this expression captures all rails requests, till the end of the log file. How do I tell this expression to stop at the first match?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
^Started.*?ActiveRecord: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1})ms\).*?$
```

Comment: I am trying to separate logs in logstash. But the logs don't have a newline. Many logs are concatenated as one. So using the line terminator doesnt work for me. Also in graylog, newlines arent respected.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the log so I can test it ?

Comment: I have created a Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/hmcykpqDLn. Have skipped many lines, but the premise is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`break_on_match => true`

source : http://blog.mmlac.com/how-to-pre-process-logs-with-logstash/